# Remove the last letter of the string using click - javascript

Tags: javascript

Sorry about this noob question, I am trying to create a button that would remove the last letter of the string just by clicking it using an EventListener. As of now, it does not work. Button 1 and 2 are working fine. The Clear button is working as well. It's just the cancel button that is not working. I am trying to use the slice method. I am not really sure how to do this and why it's not working. Please see the code below for reference.

```js
//PLACE HOLDER FOR THE RESULT
let Result = document.getElementById("result");
Result.innerText = "RESULT HERE";

// CLEAR BUTTON
let clear = document.querySelector('.clear-tasks');
// EVENT LISTENER TO CLEAR THE BUTTON
clear.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  Result.textContent = 0;
});


//ONE BUTTON  
const numberOne = document.querySelector('.one');

// EVENT LISTENER TO CONCATINATE 1
numberOne.addEventListener('click', runEventOne);

function runEventOne(e) {
  if (Result.textContent === 'RESULT HERE' || Result.textContent === '0') {
    Result.textContent = 1;
  } else {
    Result.textContent += 1;
  }
}


// TWO 
const numberTwo = document.querySelector(".two");

// EVENT LISTENER TO CONCATINATE 2 
numberTwo.addEventListener('click', runEventTwo);

function runEventTwo(e) {
  if (Result.textContent === 'RESULT HERE' || Result.textContent === '0') {
    Result.textContent = 2;
  } else {
    Result.textContent += 2;
  }
}

// CANCEL
const cancel = document.querySelector(".cancel");
cancel.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  Result.textContent.slice(0, -1);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 600px;
}

p {
  font-size: 23px;
  float: left;
  padding: 30px;
  border: solid #336336 2px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="result"></h1>


<p id="1" class="one">1</p>
<p id="2" class="two">2</p>


<br><br>


<p class="cancel">cancel</p>

<p class="clear-tasks"> CLEAR</p>
```

Comment: `Result.textContent = Result.textContent.slice(0, -1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is actually correct, the only thing is that you need to set the result of the slice method to the `Result` textContent again.

```
  // CANCEL
const cancel = document.querySelector(".cancel");
    cancel.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    Result.textContent = Result.textContent.slice(0, -1);
});
```

And voila!

P.S: Posting an answer and not a comment because I have not enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

> The slice() method extracts a section of a string and returns it as a
>   new string.

The original string is not changed.
Like the others have said...

```
Result.textContent = Result.textContent.slice(0, -1);
```